# Creating and Running a SQL Server Unit Test Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing, stored-procedures

Is there a way to create a unit test for a stored procedure in VS2015. Tried to follow [The Microsoft walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212(v=vs.103).aspx) but I don't gave the option "Create Unit Tests" right clicking on a stored procedure. I did install [SQL Server Data Tools Preview in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/mt429383). Preview...
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have a solution and by right clicking on a procedure in `Solution Explorer` I have the option `Create Unit Tests...`

Comment: Right, did it in the SQL Server Object Explorer (as told in the walkthru)... Thanks!

Comment: Check these [Microsoft SQL Server Database Development with SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBVHN1mwZl8) and [Introducing Unit Testing for SQL Server Database Projects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBB2dJKmQWU). Very helpful.

Comment: Indeed very helpful - Thanks!